# Differences between "何度も or 何度でも" and 何回も?

Tags: word-choice, counters

Things like 何度も and 何回も are somehow common. In what cases would there be differences between the two? Are they the same differences between the plain 回 and 度? Thanks.

Comment: You can use 回 and 度 interchangeably most of the time, the only big difference I know  is 今度=next time and 今回=this time.

Comment: I think the でも version has a feeling of perseverance to it: "Despite countless failures she never gave up." Whereas the other feels like the result doesn't change. Keep in mind I can only offer that opinion as a comment.

Comment: @BurakUeda 英語でうまく表現できませんが・・・「度」は回数の多さを強調しているというか、繰り返しがより重いものに感じることがあります（何回目 vs 何度目）。

Comment: @unarist So there's more stress on simple frequency or count rather than repetition with 度 compared to 回? So something like http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3060/9822 ? Sorry I'm not so good with understanding long Japanese sentences. Still kind of a beginner.

Comment: @quarks Yes, I thought like that. I think which 回 or 度 prefer is context biased, but...it may not be generally difference of 回 and 度 (and also 何回も/何度も).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While there exists a large amount of interchangeability between 「[回]{かい}」 and 「[度]{ど}」, it is also true that in certain situations, only using one of the two is either "correct" or "preferred" over the other.

> ***Interchangeable:***

***General frequency***: "X has happened Y times.", "Person X has done something Y times.", etc.

「この[冬]{ふゆ}、４回/度[雪]{ゆき}が[降]{ふ}った。」= "It snowed 4 times this winter."

「その[映画]{えいが}は2回/度[観]{み}ました。」= "I have seen the film twice."

> ***Not Interchangeable:***

1) ***Ordinal numbers***.

「[第]{だい}16**回**XYZ[大学日本語弁論大会]{だいがくにほんごべんろんたいかい}」= "The 16th Annual XYZ University Japanese Speech Contest".  Using 「度」 here is incorrect.

2) ***Proverbs and sayings***.

「二**度**あることは三**度**ある。」= "What happens twice will happen thrice."  Using 「回」 here would be extremely weird.

「三**度**[目]{め}の[正直]{しょうじき}」= "Third time lucky."  「回」 cannot be used.

3) ***Decimals***.

「アメリカ[人]{じん}は[週平均]{しゅうへいきん}8.6**回**ハンバーガーを[食]{た}べる。」= "On average, Americans eat a hamburger 8.6 times a week."  「度」 should not be used with a decimal.

4) ***Larger numbers***.

This is a strong tendency and certainly not a written rule, but we do not use 「度」 much when the number is "large".  We would ***not*** say 「140度」 or 「3800度」.  We would use 「回」 for numbers that large.

(If you used 「140度」 or 「3800度」 out of context, native speakers would think, without a fail, that you were talking about a temperature of something and not a frequency -- "140 degrees Celcius", etc.)

There could be more cases where the two words are not interchangeable, but I will leave it to the experts here.

Comment: Is there a generally agreed upon boundary for what is considered "large" in #4?

Comment: I think 4 or 5 is where 度 starts to disappear.

Comment: Ref to 2) (Proverbs and sayings), one additional useful structure with 度　is 二度と...ない where the "no second time" means "never again". So, you can use it e.g. as "納豆は二度と食べたくない". Also for this idiom, only 度　(not 回) can be used.