# What's the difference between 度 and 回?

Tags: counters

Both are counters for occurrences. Would they be interchangeable in the following sentence?

パリ行きの電車は一日に二回出発します。

Comment: Also duplicate of http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3037/1628

Comment: Keep this question open and we will have people answering it clearly based off of old answers.  It is already happening below, I am afraid.

Answer (score 1):

The followings with the sign "OK" are correct and used by Japanese nateives,

- OK: "何度もチャレンジする"
- OK: "何回もチャレンジする"
- OK: "３度目でやっと成功した"
- OK: "３回目でやっと成功した"
- OK: "試しに一度やってみたら？"
- OK: "試しに一回やってみたら？"
- OK: "早稲田には１回で合格したが、司法試験は３回（目）でやっと合格した。"
- OK: "早稲田には１度で合格したが、司法試験は３度（目）でやっと合格した。"
- OK: "第67回NHK紅白歌合戦"
- NG: "第67度NHK紅白歌合戦"

"今回はリハーサルです。" = "This time it is the rehearsal."
"今回"　means "this time"

"次回はリハーサルです。" = "Next time it'll be the rehearsal."
"次回" = "next time"

"今度はリハーサルです。" = "Next time it'll be the rehearsal."
"今度" = "next time"

We never use "次度" at all.

Some people say that "回" has clear time window, but "度" donesn't have it.

I'm for it, but I feel that it is not the well-grounded explanation.

For me, the following is the best explanation for the difference between "度" and "回."

"一度で済ませた。" = "I've got done with them at one time."

= "I've got done with variou tasks at one time."

"一回で済ませた。" = "I've got done with them at one time."

= "I've got done with the task not at several times but at one time."

= "I've got done with the task on the first time."

Answer (score 1):

They have bit different.
First, **they can sometimes be replaced**. For example:

- 彼は一度(一回)だけ学校に来た
- 一度(一回)だけ成功した

But there is unable to replaced sentence:

- 第三回運動会
- (`*`)第三度運動会

In this cases, commonly used 回. Not used 度.

1. When used 第 or 全. (第一回, etc.) (Unable to use 度)
2. When counting decimals. (1.5回) (Unable to use 度)
3. When counting the number of actions.
4. When counting event in a row.
5. When you know number of held (happened).

In this case, commonly used 度.

1. When you do *not* know number of held (happened).
2. When counting event what is hard to calculate.